# Xampp redirects to Apache2 HomePage

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp, xampp

I've installed Xampp 7.4.7 in my Ubuntu 20.04 long ago and got back recently and when I go type in localhost in my browser it redirects me to Apache2 homepage [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow1vg.png) and I remembered before that it redirects me to htdocs where it would automatically run index.php. I looked at /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf to change "DocumentRoot" [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/texIV.png) and nothing was changed except it redirects me.